# ASP.NET MVC web.config not capturing custom errors

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm trying to capture custom error in ASP.NET MVC 5

This is my `web.config` :

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/ErrorPage/DefaultErrorPage">
    <error statusCode="400" redirect="/ErrorPage/DefaultErrorPage"/>
    <error statusCode="401" redirect="/ErrorPage/Http401UnAuthorize"/>
    <error statusCode="403" redirect="/ErrorPage/Http403Forbidden"/>
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="/ErrorPage/Http404NotFound"/>
</customErrors>
.........
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
    <remove statusCode="400" />
    <remove statusCode="401" />
    <remove statusCode="403" />
    <error statusCode="400" redirect="/ErrorPage/DefaultErrorPage"  responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
    <error statusCode="401" path="/ErrorPage/Http401UnAuthorize" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    <error statusCode="403" path="/ErrorPage/Http403Forbidden" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

With these settings, most of the errors are captured and redirected to my error controller, but these urls still show this message :

[image]

Sample urls :

```
https://xxxxx.com/customError.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/open-search.gz
https://xxxxx.com/customError.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/open-search.gz
https://xxxxx.com/%22ns%3D%22EDRIS%280x000046%29
https://xxxxx.com/\../\../\../\../\../\../\../\../\../\../\../etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try adding the following in web.config:

```
 <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
     <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
     <error statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/500.aspx" />
 </httpErrors>
```